# How to get table cell value using jquery on row click and show the value to another table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want to build a view that get the value from html table and show the value to another table. I have search how to do it, but haven't found it yet.I have found a lots of way, but just getting the value. I am new in jquery and dont know how to do it. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: I am using codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#sourceTable tr').click(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo($('#destTable'));
});
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="sourceTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Source Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="destTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Dest Table</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @jack thanks for the answer. but i want to do it in ajax, and when i cliked another row it will refresh the table to a new value ? do you know how to do it ? thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the problem entirely. You have one or two tables. When you click on a row you want the table to repopulate with new values from a ajax fetch?

Comment: yes I have two tables. the top table will show the general value, and the below table will show the specific value from the top table when we clicked. and yes, the below table will repopulate with new values from a ajax fetch.

Comment: You can insert the ajax call inside the `.click` function from the snippet above. When it resolves you can then clear the second table and append results based on the ajax call, or the cloned element from before.